# Windows Server 2016 Docker image support for SQL Server?

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile

I've taken note of various Dockerfiles for SQL Server support, most recently:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/03/21/sql-server-in-windows-containers/

And, I've seen the SQL Server Image support provided by [WinDocks](http://www.windocks.com) on Windows Server 2012  but I haven't seen whether Microsoft has announced plans to support SQL Server 2016 with Docker image support on Windows Server 2016?   And, if so, has anyone heard if MS plans to include support in dockerfile support for adding or mounting databases in containers?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: The SQL Server team now maintains a 2014 Express image on Docker Hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-2014-express-windows/

SQL Server 2016 is currently a little harder to install, but 2014 works fine. Here's my (slightly hacky) Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet35

ENV SQL_EXPRESS_DOWNLOAD_URL "https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/6/156992E6-F7C7-4E55-833D-249BD2348138/ENU/x64/SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
ENV SQL_SERVER_SA_PASSWORD "Password1"

WORKDIR /

RUN powershell -Command (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%SQL_EXPRESS_DOWNLOAD_URL%', 'sqlexpress.exe')
RUN /sqlexpress.exe /qs /x:setup && /setup/setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=SQLEXPRESS /FEATURES=SQLEngine /UPDATEENABLED=0 /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=%SQL_SERVER_SA_PASSWORD% /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\System" /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS" /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS && del /F /Q sqlexpress.exe && rd /q /s setup

RUN powershell -Command \
        set-strictmode -version latest ; \
        stop-service MSSQL`$SQLEXPRESS ; \
        set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql12.SQLEXPRESS\mssqlserver\supersocketnetlib\tcp\ipall' -name tcpdynamicports -value '' ; \
        set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql12.SQLEXPRESS\mssqlserver\supersocketnetlib\tcp\ipall' -name tcpport -value 1433 ; \
        start-service MSSQL`$SQLEXPRESS

CMD powershell -Command while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
EXPOSE 1433
```

It's based on this one: https://github.com/brogersyh/Dockerfiles-for-windows/blob/master/sqlexpress/dockerfile

Comment: I'm guessing we can run this on Mac, Ubuntu ,etc? as long as we have docker engine installed? or it requires some other MS dependencies?

Comment: @Sobiaholic it requires a Windows kernel and a Windows Server 2016 system to run. On Linux or Mac, you can run that in a VM.

Answer (score 2):

Follow up on this, Microsoft released Windows Server core 1709 with support for network attached SMB shares.   I also note that Windocks has released Docker SQL Server container database cloning support, which I've tested using Core 1709,and can now service a team with 500 GB data images in roughly 1 minute.   You can see more on Windocks at https://windocks.com/docker-sql-server-containers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a full version of sql server (not only the Express version), here's how you can do it: https://github.com/mabead/Docker.SqlServer